# Return what Layout file is being used (if any) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In some of my views, at the top I specify a Layout like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDetail.cshtml";
}
```

and in `_LayoutDetail` I have:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Some other views call the main `_Layout` directly and some have a `NULL` Layout. But if the use the `_LayoutDetail` or `_LayoutList` then they also call the `_Layout` file too.

What I want to do is inside a helper is find out what Layout file is being used and return a string for a class on the body element.

For example:

```
<body class="@Html.PageClass(Layout)">
```

And in the HtmlHelper.cs

```
public static string PageClass(this HtmlHelper helper, string layout = null)
{

    if(layout === null) {

        return "layoutDefault";

    } elseif(layout == "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDetail.cshtml") {

        return "layoutDetail";

    } elseif(layout == "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutList.cshtml") {

        return "layoutList";

    } else {

        return "layoutDefault";

    }

    return layout.ToLower();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the Layout file used? And also deal with the use of Layouts in both the View and the called Layout file?

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into the reasons why you're doing this (seems very strange to me).

Either way.. here's my answer.

The `Layout` is actually part of the `WebPageBase` that Views are based on. So you can pass it into your helper like this:

```
<body class="@Html.PageClass(this.Layout)">
```

(you can omit the `this`.. since `this` is the View.. in scope)

Comment: Not working for me, as both `this.Layout` and `Layout` are always returning `null`. See my OP for what I have tried based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added this to `_Layout`

```
<body class="@(ViewBag.Layout != null ? ViewBag.Layout : "LayoutDefault")">
```

and then in the LayoutList and LayoutDetail files

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Layout = "LayoutDetail";
}
```

So if a child layout is used I pass it to the ViewBag otherwise it's always defaulted.